# Google Apps Script Authorization

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function that stores the email addresses of the users from a domain as a script property.
Initially this function worked without a problem on domain A, after creating a copy on domain B and making all the required changes, it keeps asking for authorization to Google Contacts even if I granted access several times.

Additional details:

1. The script is run from a super admin account
2. I'm using oAuth with Consumer Key and Secret
3. Under `Two-legged OAuth access control` the Allow access to all API's option is checked

If you need additional details, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I used this with Google User Authentication:

```
  $client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');
```

I'm not sure if we are talking about the same thing, but the logic might work ?!

Comment: Hi Shpat, sorry but I don't know what you are referring to, I run the script from the script editor and it keeps asking me to authorize even if I accepted it many times.

Comment: @AndreiUrse What i'm saying is: if a user is logged in in my website via google, if I DON'T use the above code, it keeps asking me and other users to authorize even if I and them accepted it many times before, but If I ADD $client->setApprovalPrompt('auto'); it asks only once, and then the next time, it doesn't, it automatically authorizes it. Please note that I have used this for Google user authentication.